# Inner Join dinamico en PL SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql

una consulta

Tengo una tabla con la estructura de un arbol, no esta muy bien hecha pero es lo que hay
Seria algo asi
Las columnas con la jerarquia y dentro el ID del valor del nodo

Nodo1 Nodo2 Nodo3 Nodo4 Nodo5

321----3543----546

43

537----3535----543----54534

Despues hay cinco tablas mas

Table Nodo1
ID NOMBRE

Table Nodo2
ID NOMBRE

Table Nodo3
ID NOMBRE

Table Nodo4
ID NOMBRE

Table Nodo5
ID NOMBRE

Hay alguna manera de hacer un inner join dependiendo el ultimo valor de la estructura del arbol para poder obtener el nombre

Por ejemplo en la primer fila de la tabla del arbol, nodo5 is null entonces nodo4 is null entonces nodo3 is null, tiene el valor 546 entonces hago el join contra Table Nodo3, asi puedo obtener el nombre

Muchas gracias

Saludos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una idea sería hacer una sql por cada nivel y unirlas por unions. Esta sql de cada nivel tiene que relacionar solo las lineas que lleguen hasta un nodo, es decir los otros nodos sean null.

Ejemplo con 3 niveles:

```
select '1' as nivel , tree.nodo1 as nodo, nodo1.id as id, nodo1.nombre as nombre
from TablaTree tree
inner join NODO1 nodo1 on nodo1.id = tree.nodo1
where 
tree.nodo2 is null and tree.nodo3 is null
union
select '2' as nivel , tree.nodo2 as nodo, nodo2.id as id, nodo2.nombre as nombre
from TablaTree tree
inner join Nodo2 nodo2 on nodo2.id = tree.nodo2
where 
tree.nodo2 is not null and tree.nodo3 is null
union
select '3' as nivel , tree.nodo3 as nodo, nodo3.id as id, nodo3.nombre as nombre
from TablaTree tree
inner join Nodo3 nodo3 on nodo3.id = tree.nodo3
where 
tree.nodo3 is not null;
```

Para estos inserts:

```
INSERT into TABLATREE  (NODO1, NODO2, NODO3) VALUES (1, null, null);
INSERT into TABLATREE  (NODO1, NODO2, NODO3) VALUES (11, null, null);
INSERT into TABLATREE  (NODO1, NODO2, NODO3) VALUES (2, 21, null);
INSERT into TABLATREE  (NODO1, NODO2, NODO3) VALUES (2, 22, null);
INSERT into TABLATREE  (NODO1, NODO2, NODO3) VALUES (3, 31, 311);
INSERT into TABLATREE  (NODO1, NODO2, NODO3) VALUES (3, 32, 321);
INSERT into node1  (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (1, 1);
INSERT into node1  (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (11, 11);
INSERT into node2  (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (21, 21);
INSERT into node2  (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (22, 22);
INSERT into node3  (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (311, 311);
INSERT into node3  (ID, NOMBRE) VALUES (321, 321);
```

Nos saldrían estos resultados:

```
Nivel Nodo  Id    Nombre
1     1     1     1
1     11    11    11
2     21    21    21
2     22    22    22
3     311   311   311
3     321   321   321
```